# ThreeJS renderer changing parent size

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

Im trying to display a fixed 550 x 500 container inside a table to display a 3D object, but for some reason when i call `container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);` my parent container changes its size to 590 x 501, any ideas on how to fix this behaviour?

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="img/obj/cojin1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </td>
            <td rowspan="3" id="canvas">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="img/obj/cojin2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="img/obj/cojin3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
if (WEBGL.isWebGLAvailable() === false) {
    document.body.appendChild(WEBGL.getWebGLErrorMessage());
}

var container, stats, controls, containerWidth, containerHeight;
var camera, scene, renderer, light, textureLoader;

init();
//loadfbx();
//animate();

function init() {
    container = document.getElementById('canvas');
    containerWidth = 550;
    containerHeight = 500;

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, containerWidth / containerHeight, 0.1, 100);
    camera.position.set(0, 3, 3);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xFFFFFF);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(containerWidth, containerHeight, false);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by padding on the cell. You can fix this via css

```
<td rowspan="3" id="canvas" style="padding: 0;height: 500px;display: block;">
```

Comment: No, it is not caused by the padding